# Ghidra loading Linux kernel function signatures

Tags: ghidra

### TLTR

I want to load Linux kernel headers vs. 4.19 to Ghidra so that it recognizes kernel structures and function signatures.

### Full description

I'm trying to reverse engineer a Linux kernel module (kernel version 4.19).
Ghidra does recognize correctly all function names such as: `open`, `misc_register`, etc., but it cannot determine their exact signatures.

Let's take as an example the `copy_from_user()` function with the signature:

```
unsigned long copy_from_user (void *to, const void __user *from, unsigned long n);
```

and here's how Ghidra sees it:

```
undefined _copy_from_user (void)
```

I believe that it won't be the last kernel module for me to reverse engineer, and so I would like to learn how to load all missing kernel structures to the program.

Moreover, I am aware that I can edit the function signature by hand, but I would then need to add plenty of structures by hand as well (such as struct file) and this would be very ineffective.

#### What I've tried so far

(I'm super new to Ghidra and if you know a better way to load Linux kernel headers, please just share.)

I've downloaded headers from Debian repository:

```
$ wget linux-headers-4.19.0-6-common_4.19.67-2+deb10u2_all.deb .
$ ls
linux-headers-4.19.0-6-common_4.19.67-2+deb10u2_all.deb  usr
$ ls /usr/src/
linux-headers-4.19.0-6-common
```

I extracted and copied the whole content of all files into `all_headers.h` (Ghidra didn't want to accept the directory itself. I couldn't find any information about loading files form Makefile as well)

```
$ cat `find . | grep .h` > all_headers.h
$ cat all_headers.h | wc -c
29824650
```

And I've provided all_headers.h to get parsed, but Ghidra has only added around 20 defines and no function signatures.

[image]

[image]